# How to make CSS property not overridden?

Tags: css

I installed a plugin in my Wordpress site, and the plugin has a CSS like this

```
.tab {
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   position: relative;
}
```

and my Wordpress theme also has a css:

```
.tab {
   height: 50px;
   font-size: 12px;
}
```

So the plugin is also using the "height" & "font-size" in the theme css.

How to avoid this? The plugin is not supposed to have the style from the theme. I was trying to change the plugin css name from "tab" to "xxxxtabs" but there is a lot of code changes in php then, so I gave up because I don't want to mess up things. I think there must be  a way to change a few lines in the css code instead?

Comment: I think you might want `!important`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: but they are different attributes?

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can add the parent class/id to the plugin's css selector like:

```
#parentidname .tab {}
```

or

```
.parentclassname .tab {}
```